# Is there any way to speed up the chopping down of trees?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I find chopping down trees to be a long and laborious process, especially when dealing with extremely tall trees, where I need to build a tower up to the top to complete the job.

Is there any way to speed up the chopping down of trees?

Comment: Close voters closing as off-topic: This seems to be on-topic as per the top-voted answer in the ff: [meta] post, [Is “mod rec” really am umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja Recommendations, mod or otherwise, are strictly off-topic. Unless there's an underlying problem that we can solve. Then we re-word it to focus on THAT problem.

Comment: The edit makes the accepted answer a bit...confusing.

Comment: @Cthos That's unfortunate... There, a quick edit to make the grammar fit fixes that.

Comment: @fbueckert As you well know, closing is for unfixable questions, editing is for mod rec that can be trivially salvaged. VTC an easily-fixable question just causes unnecessary bother as it gets closed and then reopened, and is a waste of time.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, closing is for problematic questions.  After they've been fixed, they can easily be re-opened.  It doesn't matter what the problem is; if there is one, you can either edit to fix it, or vote to close it.  I don't play Minecraft, so I vote to close.  Since this one has been edited, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @fbueckert "*Recommendations, mod or otherwise, are strictly off-topic... we re-word it to focus on THAT problem*" As per the [meta] post, [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797) (emphasis mine) - "*Mods..., etc are all solutions to problems. They don't automatically make a question good or bad for being mentioned in it, or for being the only way to solve a given question... their mention doesn't make a bad question good. **Disconnect the two, and look past the word choices and presupposed answers**.*"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [Timber!](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/119361-100-tehkrushs-mods-plasticcraft-v23-timber-and-more/#timber)

Comment: This might be the best news I've heard all day.

Answer (score 3):

[Treecapitator](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1009577-147-daftpvfs-mods-treecapitator-ingameinfo-crystalwing-startinginv-floatingruins/) does this and is highly configurable.

Answer (score 3):

Within vanilla minecraft there are a variety of methods for quickly chopping down trees.

From the original question, it is unclear if the desire is clearcutting, or harvesting massive amounts of wood.

For clearcutting, one can use flint and steel and burn the forest.  Back in the days of beta, this could cause quite a spectacle.  In current (release 1.6.4) days, fires do not get out of control, but most wood on most trees is destroyed.

For massive wood production, best to create a farm.  The single most important feature of a farm, is a top barrier to keep trees from growing too large.  (Especially important for oaks).

Once you have a farm, then

- Diamond Axes
- enchanted axes of efficiency
- [Beacons of Haste](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon)
- or [Potions of swiftness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potions)

are all mechanisms by which your harvesting will be vastly sped up.

Answer (score 1):

Thaumcraft Axe of the stream works nicely too. If you just want to harvest wood though, Forestry will let you set up a pretty much completely automated wood farm pretty easily which you can pipe into a chest with buildcraft pipes or redpower tubes.

Answer (score 1):

There are now AFK designs that cage a wither, and have the wither perform the harvesting.  All that is required is steve to plant the saplings.  So, if you want infinite wood, and have infinite bonemeal there is a path:

Comment: WOOW! This looks awesome!!